# Copy value of variable to clipboard in safari

Tags: javascript, safari, clipboard

In my vue project, I have a copy-button which should copy an attribute value from data on click:

```
<span class="btn-action" :class="!data.value.copy ? 'btn-disabled' : 'btn-active'" @click="copyCode(data.item)"><font-awesome-icon :icon="['far', 'copy']" /></span>
```

and my copyCode function:

```
copyCode: function(item) {
    // tests if item exists...    
    let copyText = item.code;
    if (navigator && navigator.clipboard) {
       console.log('navigator:', navigator);
       // this works on chrome/firefox 
       navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText);
    } else {
       console.log('no navigator');
       this.writeTextIOS(copyText);
       }
    }

writeTextIOS: function(str) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        let success = false;
        function listener(e) {
            e.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", str);
            e.preventDefault();
            success = true;
        }
        document.addEventListener("copy", listener);
        document.execCommand("copy");
        document.removeEventListener("copy", listener);
        success ? resolve() : reject();
    });
},
```

I found out on safari, there is navigator, but this does not have clipboard property (I could probably check `navigator.userAgent` as well, but that is not the issure here, since it definately go into else-statement when I am using safari).
I got the writeTextIOS function from here: https://gist.github.com/lgarron/d1dee380f4ed9d825ca7 But I only get an `Unhandled Promise Rejectio: undefined` exception.

So what should I do here. I don't want to use any third-party package like clipboard.js (yet). Is there any "native" solution for my problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy to clipboard using Javascript in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045777/copy-to-clipboard-using-javascript-in-ios)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40147676/javascript-copy-to-clipboard-on-safari

Comment: nope, since I don't want to copy anything from DOM, plus I thought document.execCommand('copy') is not supported in safari?

Comment: Have you tried the `document.execCommand('copy')` as explained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard#Writing_to_the_clipboard

Comment: as I said, I am trying to copy a data attribute which is a string, not something from the DOM